# Log action in Spring Boot Admin

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-admin

How to configure Spring Boot Admin to log action. For example, I want Spring Boot Admin log action when someone change log level form INFO to DEBUG or when someone change configuration value in JMX tab and write wrong configure override the existing.

Do Spring Boot Admin has a feature to do that?

Answer (score 1):

No it doesn't but you could write a zuul filter intercepting, analyzing the request to `/api/applications/{id}/logfile` and writing a log statement.

Answer (score 0):

> Spring Boot includes a number of additional features to help you
>   monitor and manage your application when it’s pushed to production.
>   You can choose to manage and monitor your application using HTTP
>   endpoints, with JMX or even by remote shell (SSH or Telnet). Auditing,
>   health and metrics gathering can be automatically applied to your
>   application.
>
> Actuator HTTP endpoints are only available with a Spring MVC-based
>   application. In particular, it will not work with Jersey unless you
>   enable Spring MVC as well.

You can also activate a listener by invoking the SpringApplication.addListeners(…​) method and passing the appropriate Writer object. This method also allows you to customize the file name and path via the Writer constructor.

**Customize your requirement in Actuator**

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready

Maven :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

http://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-authentication-audit